# Parsing this JSON using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I am using JQuery to make a call to my WCF service. The response body shows my JSON format data but I am not sure how to parse through it. See my code for what I have done so far.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/GetNotes()?$format=json",
            type: "get",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    alert(data[i].Title);
                })
            }
        });

    });
```

**This is my JSON**

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/tblNotes(guid'93629a5f-2bb3-4190-b876-3d8a2997e76a')",
                "uri": "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/tblNotes(guid'93629a5f-2bb3-4190-b876-3d8a2997e76a')",
                "type": "GenesisOnlineModel.tblNote"
            },
            "NotesID": "93629a5f-2bb3-4190-b876-3d8a2997e76a",
            "NotesTitle": "BSKYB",
            "NotesText": "new Director of Brand and Media ",
            "ParentID": 8879,
            "ContactID": 309,
            "JobID": 1000088150,
            "UserID": "8b0e303a-68aa-49a5-af95-d994e2bdd5ac",
            "GroupID": null,
            "RelatedType": "Advertiser Contact",
            "IsShared": true
        },
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/tblNotes(guid'0f21866b-4a5c-417f-afe1-70ffbd1ce1f3')",
                "uri": "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/tblNotes(guid'0f21866b-4a5c-417f-afe1-70ffbd1ce1f3')",
                "type": "GenesisOnlineModel.tblNote"
            },
            "NotesID": "0f21866b-4a5c-417f-afe1-70ffbd1ce1f3",
            "NotesTitle": "BSKYB More",
            "NotesText": "Contacted all major contacts on this profile",
            "ParentID": 8879,
            "ContactID": null,
            "JobID": null,
            "UserID": "8b0e303a-68aa-49a5-af95-d994e2bdd5ac",
            "GroupID": null,
            "RelatedType": "Advertiser",
            "IsShared": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In my Success function block of code I am getting undefined in my alert. Any help would be great.

Comment: Try printing the entire `data` variable to the console. One thought would be that since the key "Title" does not exist, this is the problem rather than parsing.

Comment: I am using Chrome's web developer tools to look at the network request and response. It returns a body of JSON. I can also type the service URL to see the JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close! In your success block, do the following:

```
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {
                alert(item.NotesTitle);
            })
        }
```

Update: implemented @Johans comment.

Answer (score 2):

You are alerting `alert(data[i].Title);`. By the looks of your JSON, none of your objects in the JSON array objects even has a `Title` property, which is why you are getting `undefined`. I see `NotesTitle` but no `Title`. Change it to:

```
success: function (data) {
     $.each(data.d, function(i, item) {
          alert(item.NotesTitle);
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Changing data to data.d was what I was mising. I knew it was something small I was mising :(

Comment: I have, your JQuery prowess is too quick for SO :)